# Is there a way to download mathview as .jar?

Tags: android

I wanted to use mathview for mathematical formulas in my project.I tried to follow the steps "[here](https://github.com/jianzhongli/MathView)". But  this error appeared:

```
"implementation ("io.github.kexanie:MathView:0.5.0")" gives the following error despite adding it to the dependencies: Failed to resolve: io.github.kexanie:MathView:0.5.0
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle.kts">app</a>
```

I am using the latest version of Android studio 2022.3.1.  I don't know if it is due to incompatibilities with the new version. How can I solve this and also is there anything else I can use instead?

```
What I added to the dependencies section:
    
dependencies {

    implementation (fileTree("include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs'"))
    implementation ("io.github.kexanie:MathView:0.0.6")
   ...
/* implementation("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0")
 I did not use this because I received such a warning:
  Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward.*/
}
```

Also, is it possible to find this library as .jar?

Comment: That library has not been modified in 7 years, and the site it used to be distributed through has been discontinued. I recommend that you find a newer library, perhaps one that is currently supported.

Comment: I found a library called mathjax, I will try it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since the .aar file can't be downloaded, you always may clone the repo, build it locally and then attach the build artifact to your project as a dependency.
Or you just may follow CommonsWare's advice and use another math library.

Comment: As I told CommonsWare, I found a library called mathjax and I will try it. Thank you.